# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magent7.catalog_url_rewrite_product_category' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am migrating from Magento open source 1.9 to 2.3.3
the initial migration went well, however, I am trying to do delta migration by using Magento migration tool.

Running the delta command for migration tool gives me the error

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   `'magent7.catalog_url_rewrite_product_category'` doesn't exist

Although, the table is existing, but I believe the tool doesn't add the database prefix before forming the query.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: please access to file app/etc/env.php then check whether table_prefix is correctly config or not

Comment: Yes, it is correctly configured @BlaireJohnson

Comment: To make it more clear, that the initial migration went smoothly, i only had this issue when using delta mode

Answer (score 0):

run the reindexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

then upgrade setup

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then flush cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

hpefully this helps

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately the solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i could find the solution, i believe it is a bug in the migration tool and need to be fixed for the next update.
However, the solution is as following:

1. Edit the file

   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/UrlRewrite/Version191to2000Delta.php
2. replace the code in line #151

old code:

```
$select->from(Version191to2000::DESTINATION_PRODUCT_CATEGORY)
```

new code:

```
$select->from(addDocumentPrefix(Version191to2000::DESTINATION_PRODUCT_CATEGORY))
```

the previous change will add the database prefix to the SQL query.